# PPDB paraphases searching

Tags: mongodb, nlp, bigdata, database

There is a well known lexical resources of paraphrases [PPDB](http://paraphrase.org/).

It comes with several forms from the biggest precision to the biggest recall. The biggest set XXXL for paraphrases contains ~5Gb of data.

I want PPDB for my research and I wounder what is the best engine to perform searching in such a big resources. I didn't try but I think to use it as is in file is not a good idea.

I was thinking about to export all the data to mongo, but I am not sure if this the best solution.

Please if you have some ideas share them with us.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you give us some more info w.r.t why you want to go with MongoDB??

Comment: @vmr, I want to export data to mongo and then I want run queries, search for paraphases, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to consider the following aspects:
1. For your use-case you will need a schemaless database
2. Transactions not required
3. Fast queries/searching
4. Easy to setup and deploy
5. Ability to handle large volumes of data

All the above aspects indicate to adopt MongoDB.
But you will have teething troubles to export data to MongoDB, but it is definitely worth the effort. Your data model can be as follows {key:[value1,value2,.....]} for each document.